# I get -104 using scroll with declare in stored procedure on db2 express c 10.1

Tags: db2, procedure, declare, db2-luw

I'm running db2 express c on windows vista.
I have successfully created a procedure that does declare cursor, open, fetch and close.
It runs successfully via clp.
But as soon as I try to add scroll/noscroll to a declare, I get -104.

Answer (score 1):

Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows(LUW)  (as implied by Express-C) rejects your syntax because it is invalid for Db2-LUW.

The syntax for DECLARE CURSOR in Version 10.1 of Db2-LUW is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000937.html).

With Db2-LUW, scrollable-cursors are available if you program in jdbc, SQLJ, or CLI. They are not relevant for SQL PL stored-procedures (if the is what you are using) or their result-sets.

The mainframe version (Db2 v11 for z/OS) supports the scrollability options for DECLARE CURSOR, but the Linux/Unix/Windows Db2 v11 does not support those options.

Maybe clarify what you seek to achieve, via which programming language(s) and via which methods and platforms etc.

Comment: Thanx, you are quite right, scrollable cursors, in DECLARE, are not available til db2 v11.

Comment: Your comment is not correct for Db2-LUW (as you are using Db2 Express-C).  The mainframe version (Db2 v11 for z/OS) supports that syntax for scrollability in DECLARE CURSOR , but Db2 for Linux/Unix does not support that syntax at v11.x

Answer (score 0):

Did you try scroll/noscroll along with Dynamic/Static and sensitive/ insensitive, something like SENSITIVE STATIC SCROLL.